# How to make sample space of the following question

Tags: self-study, sampling, sample-size, sample

My teacher gave me a question to solve.In the book of Ronald E. Walpole (Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists), chapter no#3 exercise 1,question #2 which is as below:

> 3.2) An overseas shipment of 5 foreign automobiles contains 2 that have slight paint blemishes. If an agency receives 3 of these
>   automobiles at random, list the elements of the sample space S, using
>   the letters B and N for blemished and nonblemished, respectively; then
>   to each sample point assign a value x of the random variable X
>   representing the number of automobiles with paint blemishes purchased
>   by the agency.

It means we have 2 DEFECTIVE AND 3 NON-DEFECTIVE automobiles;

But in the solution manual he makes samples as follows:

```
Sample Space 
NNN 
NNB 
NBN 
BNN 
NBB 
BNB 
BBN 
BBB
```

but the question is how did he make the last sample {BBB}.I think it is not possible because we have maximum 2 blemished automobiles.and we are recieving 3 means repetition not allowed.Please tell me how {BBB} is possible.

Comment: Because this is a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag to your question. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: A generous reading of the information is that two automobiles have been found *so far* to have blemishes (perhaps by means of sampling two autos out of the shipment).  This does not completely exclude the possibility that three, four, or even all five have blemishes.  (But this is a poor exercise regardless.  It could be made more useful by supposing the shipment is known to have (at least) three blemished cars, for then some of the unordered triples would be ruled out: NNN could not occur.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBB would have been a possible sample if the simple random sample had been drawn **with replacement**.  In with-replacement simple random sampling, each selected item is "replaced" before the next draw is made. Each of the three draws is made from the original five, with probability of selection 1 in 5 at each draw.

This is a valid sampling method, but the description of the problem makes it clear that sampling was without replacement. I conclude that you are correct: A BBB sample point is impossible, and the listing in the solutions manual is in error.

Answer (score 1):

As it is obvious, that we have two blemished cars, so it is not possible to select three from two,it is just anerror or a mistake by writer or publisher..